# Assign the row sequence for each customer from the row where amount is greater than zero

Tags: sql, oracle11g, teradata

I want to assign the row sequence for each customer from the row where amount is greater than zero.
sequencing always should start from the row where amount is zero.
Here is sample data with expected output (expected_sequence).

| customer | trans_date | Amount | expected_sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | $0 | null |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 | $100 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-03-02 | $200 | 2 |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | $100 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-02-01 | $0 | 2 |
| 2 | 2023-03-02 | $150 | 3 |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 | $0 | null |
| 3 | 2023-02-01 | $0 | null |
| 3 | 2023-03-02 | $150 | 1 |
| 4 | 2023-01-01 | $0 | null |
| 4 | 2023-02-01 | $0 | null |
| 4 | 2023-03-02 | $0 | null |

Comment: What happens is, for a single customer, that the Amount goes from $0 to $100 then $200 then back to $0? is $0 always NULL?

Comment: Are you using Oracle 11g or Teradata? Please correct your tags as these are completely different products and the solution may well be product-specific

Comment: Also, why is the 5th row in your table not expected to have a null sequence - the value is zero?

Comment: In the sequence of transactions, the first sequence always should have an amount greater than zero, and after it, the amount can be zero or greater than zero. This is because the first sequence represents the initial transaction, which must have a positive amount. All subsequent transactions in the sequence can have an amount of zero or greater than zero, depending on the nature of the transaction.so the 5th row is expected to have sequence 2.

Comment: Amount always consistent, it won't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a subquery to fetch the date of first transaction per customer and start sequencing from that date on.

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl (CUSTOMER, TRANS_DATE, AMOUNT) AS
        (   Select 1, DATE '2023-01-01', 0 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, DATE '2023-02-01', 100 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, DATE '2023-03-02', 200 From Dual Union All
            
            Select 2, DATE '2023-01-01', 100 From Dual Union All
            Select 2, DATE '2023-02-01', 0 From Dual Union All
            Select 2, DATE '2023-03-02', 150 From Dual Union All
            
            Select 3, DATE '2023-01-01', 0 From Dual Union All
            Select 3, DATE '2023-02-01', 0 From Dual Union All
            Select 3, DATE '2023-03-02', 150 From Dual Union All
            
            Select 4, DATE '2023-01-01', 0 From Dual Union All
            Select 4, DATE '2023-02-01', 0 From Dual Union All
            Select 4, DATE '2023-03-02', 0 From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--    M a i n   S Q L :
Select    t.CUSTOMER, t.TRANS_DATE, AMOUNT,
          Sum(Case When t.TRANS_DATE >= f.FIRST_TRANS_DATE Then 1 End) 
                Over(Partition By t.CUSTOMER Order By t.CUSTOMER, t.TRANS_DATE 
                     Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) "SEQ"
From      tbl t
Left Join ( Select    CUSTOMER, Min(TRANS_DATE) "FIRST_TRANS_DATE"
            From      tbl
            Where     AMOUNT > 0
            Group By  CUSTOMER
          ) f ON(f.CUSTOMER = t.CUSTOMER)
Order By  t.CUSTOMER, t.TRANS_DATE
/*      R e s u  l t :
CUSTOMER    TRANS_DATE  AMOUNT      SEQ
--------  ----------  --------  -------
       1  2023-01-01         0     null
       1  2023-02-01       100        1
       1  2023-03-02       200        2
       2  2023-01-01       100        1
       2  2023-02-01         0        2
       2  2023-03-02       150        3
       3  2023-01-01         0     null
       3  2023-02-01         0     null
       3  2023-03-02       150        1
       4  2023-01-01         0     null
       4  2023-02-01         0     null
       4  2023-03-02         0     null         */
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always want NULL when amount is 0

```
select
      customer
    , trans_date
    , amount
    , row_number() over(partition by customer
                        order by trans_date, amount) as expected_sequence
from your_table
where amount <> 0
```

nb: it isn't known if amount can be less than zero, so `<> 0` has been used, if amount is always 0 or positive the you could use `> 0` instead. Also, ordering of row number uses amount as a tiebreaker if more than 1 amount shares a date, this is optional or there may be better tiebreaker columns to use.

Comment: amount cant be null always

Comment: OK, amount is not null, but can amount be less than zero?  if yes then use `<> 0`, if no then use `> 0` - it isn't that important `<> 0` will work for yes or no.

Comment: Amount can be less than zero